# How to center CSS Navigation Menu

Tags: css, menu, centering, nav

Please can someone help? 
How can I centre this CSS menu? 
See below for the beginning of the code 
Whatever I try doesn't seem to work. 
I'm sure it is quite simple really but I cannot figure it out.
Thanks in advance!

```
#cssmenu {
  position: relative;
  height: 44px;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;     
  vertical-align: top; 
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 32px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 500;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position:relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans';
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: #000000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 32px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #000000;
}
#cssmenu li.has-sub::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub::after {
  right: 10px;
  top: 20px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #000000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover::after {
  border-top-color: #000000;
}
```

***HTML***

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML code too.

Comment: There is no strict HTML code, I followed the steps on here: http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/wordpress-3-drop-down-menu-tutorial

Comment: Most likely you need to give the menu and its container a width, then set margin-left and margin-right of the menu to "auto", but without seeing the HTML it's obviously hard to tell.

Comment: It's hard to do anything without the HTML, but generally, `margin: auto` will often center elements, however if it's a div or block-level element, it will automatically expand to fit it's container because of the `width: auto` so it doesn't really "center". Also, `float: left` will probably keep it from centering, I would try taking that out.

Comment: Just added the html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it is by setting the display type of `#cssmenu`  to `inline-block` and then wrap everything in a container with `text-align: center`. You also need to set `text-align: left` on `#cssmenu` such that the text aligns correctly again.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls7kJ/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm going to assume that in your HTML, the #cssmenu element is the one you are trying to center.
As others have said, block elements can be centered by using a `width:` and a `margin: 0 auto`.

The dilema here is that if you set a width to it, then you have to adjust the width everytime the menu items change, so what I do is leave it without a `width` attribute and only enhance it (center it) for users with JS support.

If using jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
function navCenter(){
  if($('#cssmenu').length){
    var ulWidth = 0;
    $('#cssmenu > ul > li').each(function(){
      ulWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    });

    $('#cssmenu').css('width', ulWidth);
  }
}
```

So the above piece of code sets a width on the #cssmenu element and the css applies a `margin: 0 auto`, centering it.

Let me know if this make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can center the ul with all its list-items in a container without js or jquery. There's no need to adjust something if the list-items are changed.

```
<div class="menuwrapper">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

.menuwrapper {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav, .nav li, .nav a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.nav {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav li {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  right: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: bold 16px arial,sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  outline: 0;
}
```